# Material UI TextField type='search': How to replace/modify the 'clear' icon?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

In the following example I'm using a text field with type='search'.
[image]

The 'clear' icon appears automatically. How can I change the styling of this icon or replace it with my own icon?

```
import SearchIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Search';
    
<TextField
   placeholder="Search"
   type="search"
   variant="outlined"
   fullWidth
   size="small"
   onChange={handleSearchFieldOnChange}
   InputProps={{
       startAdornment: (
           <InputAdornment position="start">
              <SearchIcon />
           </InputAdornment>
            ),
         }}
 />
```

Comment: you really need your TextField to be search type?
Because if not you can pass type to text and add your custom icon in InputAdorment with an IconButton for exemple

Comment: Yeah that's what I ended up doing yesterday but was curious to find the answer for the above.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

you can do something like this:

```
import InputAdornment from "@material-ui/core/InputAdornment";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import SearchIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Search";
import { IconButton } from "@material-ui/core";
import CancelRoundedIcon from '@material-ui/icons/CancelRounded'
export default function InputWithIcon() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  return (
    <TextField
      placeholder="Search"
      type="text"
      variant="outlined"
      fullWidth
      size="small"
      onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
      value={value}
      InputProps={{
        startAdornment: (
          <InputAdornment position="start">
            <SearchIcon />
          </InputAdornment>
        ),

        endAdornment: value && (
          <IconButton
            aria-label="toggle password visibility"
            onClick={() => setValue("")}
          ><CancelRoundedIcon/></IconButton>
        )
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

see the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/withered-cdn-i1vfh?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 2):

We can use IconButton to place the clear event. Whenever we have value the clear icon is visible, otherwise it will be disable

**Example:**

```
   <TextField
      placeholder="Search"
      type="text"
      variant="outlined"
      fullWidth
      size="small"
      onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
      value={value}
      InputProps={{
        endAdornment: (
          <IconButton onClick={() => setValue("")}>
           {value.length > 0 ? <ClearOutlinedIcon/> : ''}
          </IconButton>
        )
      }}
    />
```